# AS3 .swf file not playing or previewing when uploaded to server

Tags: html, object, flash, embed, swfobject

Help needed.

I have a .swf file of a flash game created using AS3. I have added it to a HTML file using object tag. When I test file locally in a browser window on my MAC it plays .swf file. The file is contained in the same folder as html file. When I upload it to server and review on FF/Chrome/Safari it will only display white boxes.

Previously I tried using jquery swfobject, same issue.

I've stripped down the code to bear minimun and used to different examples found online and am having no luck.

Code Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<object
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash /swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param name="SRC" value="BodyShopGame.swf">
<embed src="BodyShopGame.swf"></embed>
</object>

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="339" height="513">
<param name="movie" value="BodyShopGame.swf">
<embed src="BodyShopGame.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="339" height="513"></embed>

</object> 

</body>
</html>
```

Site Link: http://www.stellacurley.com/flashtest.html

I've also tested on a PC and issue is the same. I know I have overlooked something obvious but have spent a long time trying to figure out the answer. I'm new to this, so any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A white box commonly indicates the movie failed to load. Use your browser's developer console to see if the request for the SWF is returning a 404 (file not found) error.

Checklist:

1. Ensure you're using the correct path to the SWF
2. Ensure your SWF has been uploaded
3. Ensure your SWF is properly named (case-sensitive on some servers)
4. Ensure your server is configured to host SWF files (mime type `application/x-shockwave-flash` should be enabled)